# Explanation of entries in dmesg log in Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive, filesystem, ext4

A few days ago I did a clean install of Ubuntu Server 14.04. Everything is working fine, but when my system boots I get these entries in dmesg log:

```
[    3.106082] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.864002] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    3.949562] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[    3.952774] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[    3.969238] EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.088581] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.125580] EXT4-fs (sdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.167318] EXT4-fs (sde1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.273420] EXT4-fs (sdf1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.305094] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Is this something I should be worrying about or is this normal? If it's an error is there any way to fix it?

Comment: These messages look perfectly normal to me.

Comment: Thank you Jos, I wasn't sure if these messages were normal or not, I think I can sleep better now, I was about to do a clean install all over again.

Comment: FYI, I get the same messages at boot time. You seem to run an unusual number of disks though.

Comment: Jos, what do you mean by "unusual number of disks"? It's media server/backup server which streams media to all my devices and backs up a Ubuntu 12.04 machine and a Win 7 machine. I'm not running any raid or anything like that on that server. SSD for OS and HDD for the storage. Thank you Jos for your help.

Comment: I noticed sda1 through sdf1 as well as dm-0 and dm-2 - which suggests 8 physical disks, not partitions, in all. Now you may very well have a large stack of disk drives attached to your server. Again, nothing wrong with that. Or I may be mistaken and you have a different setup.

Comment: Jos, when I was installing the server I choose  "Guided - use entire disk and set up LVM" so dm-0, dm-2 is part of the device mapper in the kernel, used by LVM, dm-0 & dm-1 are the Logical volume managers' logical volumes I have created while installing server OS onto the SSD.